# The current path, didn’t match any of these

Tags: django, django-urls

Hi I am new to django and I have been making a CRUD project,while pressing the 'EDIT' button the below error comes
[image]

heres the code in main urls.py

urls.py

```
from django.urls import  path
from categories import views
from django.urls.conf import include  
from django.conf import settings  
from django.conf.urls.static import static  



urlpatterns=[
    path('',views.show_cat,name="show_cat"),
    path('insert_cat/',views.insert_cat,name="insert_cat"),
    path('edit_cat/<int:id>/',views.edit_cat,name="edit_cat"),
    path('del_cat/',views.del_cat,name="del_cat")
]
```

edit_cat in views.py

```
def edit_cat(request,id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        print('GET',id)
        editcategory = Categories.objects.filter(id=id).first()
        s= CategoriesSerializer(editcategory)
        return render(request,'polls/edit_cat.html',{"Categories":s.data})
    else:
        print('POST',id)
        editcategory = {}
        
        d = Categories.objects.filter(id=id).first()
        if d:
            editcategory['category_name']=request.POST.get('category_name')
            editcategory['category_description']=request.POST.get('category_description')
            print(editcategory)
        # Updateemp = EmpModel.objects.get(id=id)
            #print(Updateemp)
            form = CategoriesSerializer(d,data=editcategory)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                print("hkjk",form.data)
                messages.success(request,'Record Updated Successfully...!:)')
                return redirect('categories:show_cat')
            else:
                print(form.errors)
```

is there a silly mistake I have made in the codes? please help

Comment: try to go http://127.0.0.1:8000/categories/edit_cat/2

Comment: share your main urls.py which under project folder

Comment: ```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.urls import  path
from polls import views
from django.urls.conf import include  
from django.conf import settings  
from django.conf.urls.static import static 

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/',include(('polls.urls','polls'),namespace='polls')),
    path('categories/',include(('categories.urls','categories'),namespace="categories")),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

if settings.DEBUG:  
        urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: hi enes the link worked,I have shared the main urls.py content

Comment: okay, happy hacking!

Comment: ``` from django.contrib import admin from django.urls import path,include from django.urls import path from polls import views from django.urls.conf import include from django.conf import settings from django.conf.urls.static import static urlpatterns = [ path('polls/',include(('polls.urls','polls'),namespace='polls')), path('categories/',include(('categories.urls','categories'),namespace="categories")), path('admin/', admin.site.urls), ] if settings.DEBUG: urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) ```
 any  mistake I have made which has caused the error?

Comment: Please edit your question, dont post your code to comments. And share how you include this urls.py to the main urls.py (with admin, media and so on).

Comment: edited the qestion and have included the code for main urls and urls

Comment: Can you show the part where you redirect to this url ? It seems like the error comes from there

Comment: I have put the edit function in the qestions

Comment: `included the code for main urls and urls` it does not seem so. still only one urls.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the URL with it's name to avoid errors. e.g.:

```
{% url 'edit_cat' 2 %}
```